# How do plot a bar chart with three variables where the x axis is non numerical?

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
PREMIUM_CUSTOMER    LIFESTAGE              Total Sales
Budget              OLDER FAMILIES          156863.75
Mainstream          YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES   147582.20
Mainstream          RETIREES                145168.95
Budget              YOUNG FAMILIES          129717.95
Budget              OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES   127833.60
Mainstream          OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES   124648.50
Premium             OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES   123537.55
Budget              RETIREES                105916.30
Mainstream          OLDER FAMILIES          96413.55
Premium             RETIREES                91296.65
Mainstream          YOUNG FAMILIES          86338.25
Mainstream          MIDAGE SINGLES/COUPLES  84734.25
Premium             YOUNG FAMILIES          78571.70
Premium             OLDER FAMILIES          75242.60
Budget              YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES   57122.10
Premium             MIDAGE SINGLES/COUPLES  54443.85
Premium             YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES   39052.30
Budget              MIDAGE SINGLES/COUPLES  33345.70
Budget              NEW FAMILIES            20607.45
Mainstream          NEW FAMILIES            15979.70
Premium             NEW FAMILIES            10760.80
```

The code below isn't giving me the result I want

```r
ggplot(Total_Sales, aes(x = LIFESTAGE, fill = PREMIUM_CUSTOMER)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill") +  labs(x = "Lifestage", y = "Premium customer flag", title = "Proportion of sales") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5))
```

I want the x axis to be `LIFESTAGE`, the Y axis to be Total Sales and the bars be filled with `PREMIUM CUSTOMER` and `Total sales`.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help for formatting questions. Thanks!

Comment: attach your data via `dput(your_data)` then we can help you

Comment: To add some context to @SametSökel's request, Nonsorich: often we can copy the text of the data.frame and just read from the clipboard; however, two things spoil this: (1) spaces in any column-name or data; and (2) when the `class` of a column is in question, since the console representation is not always unambiguous. The output from `dput(.)` is immediately usable (strings are properly quoted, class is preserved) and easy enough: just type `dput(your_data)` or, if big, `dput(head(your_data))` onto your console, [edit] your question, and paste into a code-block (see prev link). Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a small reprex, which might help you.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)
#> 
#> Attache Paket: 'scales'
#> The following object is masked from 'package:purrr':
#> 
#>     discard
#> The following object is masked from 'package:readr':
#> 
#>     col_factor

df <- structure(list(
  PREMIUM_CUSTOMER = c("Budget", "Mainstream", "Mainstream", "Budget", 
                       "Budget", "Mainstream", "Premium", "Budget", "Mainstream",
                       "Premium", "Mainstream", "MIDAGE", "Premium", "Premium", 
                       "Budget", "Premium", "Premium", "Budget", "Budget", 
                       "Mainstream", "Premium"
                       ), 
  LIFESTAGE = c("OLDER FAMILIES", "YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES", "RETIREES", 
                "YOUNG FAMILIES", "OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES", 
                "OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES", "OLDER SINGLES/COUPLES", "RETIREES",
                "OLDER FAMILIES", "RETIREES", "YOUNG FAMILIES", 
                "SINGLES/COUPLES", "YOUNG FAMILIES", "OLDER FAMILIES", 
                "YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES", "MIDAGE SINGLES/COUPLES", 
                "YOUNG SINGLES/COUPLES", "MIDAGE SINGLES/COUPLES", "NEW FAMILIES",
                "NEW FAMILIES", "NEW FAMILIES"),
  `Total Sales` = c("156863.75", "147582.20", "145168.95", "129717.95", 
                    "127833.60", "124648.50", "123537.55", "105916.30", 
                    "96413.55",  "91296.65", "86338.25", "84734.25", "78571.70",
                    "75242.60", "57122.10", "54443.85", "39052.30", "33345.70",
                    "20607.45", "15979.70", "10760.80")), 
  row.names = c(NA, -21L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

df <- df %>% 
  mutate(`Total Sales` = as.numeric(`Total Sales`),
         across(where(is.character), factor))

df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = LIFESTAGE, y = `Total Sales`, fill = PREMIUM_CUSTOMER)) +
  geom_col() + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels = comma) + 
  labs(x = "Lifestage",
       y = "Premium customer flag", 
       title = "Proportion of sales") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

If you need to change the plot, you are free to do so. It is important change the data type to `factor` before plotting. You should also check the fill the correct columns in the respective arguments of the `aes()` function.

Greetings,
M.